# Error (EvaluationException) on executing setSelectionFormula in XPage - Javascript code

Tags: javascript, xpages, lotus-notes

When using XPages in Lotus Domino Designer, I encounter the following error (displayed in log file) on trying to set the view formula dynamically. 
**com.ibm.xsp.exception.EvaluationExceptionEx: Error while executing JavaScript computed expression**

The following code fails ...

```
var helpview:NotesView = db.getView(viewNm); 

var strQS:string= sessionScope.searchKey; 

helpview.setSelectionFormula(strQS);
```

Error takes place at the setSelectionFormula line. strQS is the string for view selection formula.

Answer (score 0):

This message just means there's an error in your code. Error handling will identify more details of why. Something like [XPages OpenLog Logger](https://openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20OpenLog%20Logger) (which is also incorporated into OpenNTF Domino API, if you also want that) will identify the cause. XPages OpenLog Logger captures the cause regardless of whether or not there is specific error handling on that block, providing a custom error page is added to the application.

The most probable cause, though, is that the user the database is being retrieved under does not have at least Designer access to the database, either in the ACL or Maximum Internet Access on the Advanced tab of the ACL.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The same code is working in UAT. I am encountering this only in Production.

Comment: When I changed the access level for user to Designer, it worked for the first time. Then subsequently it did not work. I am even refreshing the view post selection formula. ... helpview.refresh(); Can anyone provide any suggestion?

Comment: When you say "it did not work", do you mean it's not updating the view index or not returning the expected documents. `.refresh()` is not an instantaneous task and I don't think it's a blocking task, so it may not be up-to-date. If you're regularly changing the view selection formula and re-indexing, you may be better (speed, performance, concurrency) to build a NoteCollection and iterate the IDs.

Comment: It is not returning the expected documents. In my functionality, (i) when I click on 'download all', all the documents are retrieved without changing the selection formula. But, (ii) if I select the start and end date and then click on 'download', the selection formula is updated using the start and end date and only the subset of the documents is returned. When I execute (ii), rather than retrieving the subset of documents, all the documents are returned. So, either setSelectionFormula is not working or I need to do something more to make it work.

Comment: If you look at the view after your code has run, you'll be able to confirm if `setSelectionFormula()` has worked. Access is the only reason it wouldn't, as far as I know. But I'm not sure how to identify how long the refresh of the view index takes. I don't know if it's possible that the `refresh()` has not yet completed before you've downloaded the documents.

Comment: seSelectionFormula is not working. So, Now I am using FTSearch. But I need to construct the query for selecting documents based on field value (in Javascript). Can u please provide any example or guide me to a relevant post?

Comment: Final Comment. 
I removed setSelectionComment() and used db.getSearch() and iterated through the resultant NotesDocumentCollection